# Unable to adjust height of div Twitter Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

having an issue, it's early in the morning so it's probably very simple! basically this is my code:

```
<div class="form-group">
    <label>Preview</label>
        <div style="border:1px solid black; height:2px!important;"class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-4by3">
            <iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="//player.vimeo.com/video/{{$video->link}}"></iframe>
        </div>
</div>
```

For some reason I cannot set the height of the video `div`. Currently the problem is that the `iframe` is sized correctly, but the containing `div` has an unnecessary height which is pushing the `form submit` `button` down out of the user's view. I would like to be able to adjust the height of the `div`

Comment: just going out on a limb here and ask....what button? Can we have a jsfiddle showing this behaviour?

Comment: Also need a space before `!important`.

Comment: It works fine. height:2px; is being applied. Check this http://jsfiddle.net/db5srcn9/1/